# Unable to install new software in 16.04

Tags: apt, software-installation, 16.04, dpkg

I try to install a new software in Ubuntu 16.04.
I cannot install but I get a following error:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
aptitude : Conflicts: aptitude:i386
aptitude:i386 : Depends: libapt-pkg4.12:i386 (>= 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu6) but it is not installable
Depends: libboost-iostreams1.46.1:i386 (>= 1.46.1-1) but it is not installable
Depends: libcwidget3:i386 but it is not installable
Depends: libept1.4.12:i386 but it is not installable
Depends: libncursesw5:i386 (>= 5.6+20070908) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a:i386 (>= 2.0.2) but it is not installable
Depends: libxapian22:i386 but it is not installable
Recommends: apt-xapian-index:i386 but it is not installable
Recommends: libparse-debianchangelog-perl:i386 but it is not installable
Conflicts: aptitude
aptitude-common : Breaks: aptitude:i386 (< 0.6.8-1)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

I tried `apt-get install -f` that is also not working

Below error is appear

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
apt:i386 aptitude:i386 libapt-pkg5.0:i386 libboost-iostreams1.58.0:i386<br>
libbz2-1.0:i386 libcwidget3v5:i386 libgpm2:i386 liblz4-1:i386
libncursesw5:i386 libsigc++-2.0-0v5:i386 libxapian22v5:i386
Suggested packages:
apt-doc:i386 python-apt:i386 apt-xapian-index:i386 aptitude-doc-en:i386
| aptitude-doc:i386 debtags:i386 tasksel:i386 libcwidget-dev:i386 gpm:i386
xapian-tools:i386
Recommended packages:
libparse-debianchangelog-perl:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
apt apt-utils ubuntu-minimal unattended-upgrades
The following NEW packages will be installed:
apt:i386 libapt-pkg5.0:i386 libboost-iostreams1.58.0:i386 libbz2-1.0:i386
libcwidget3v5:i386 libgpm2:i386 liblz4-1:i386 libncursesw5:i386
libsigc++-2.0-0v5:i386 libxapian22v5:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
aptitude:i386
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!    apt
1 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 4 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 4,480 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,370 kB of additional disk space will be used.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
?] sudo apt autoremove
Abort.
```

Please help me how to fix this error.

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get -f install` ?

Comment: Already i tried but i get another one error

Comment: @vinothkumar: Could you please [edit] your question to include that error as well.

Comment: I updated my code

Comment: Try to indent your code by 4 spaces instead of making bold so it can be read easier. On topic: I am not sure I can see the 4 packages that are to be deleted. Plus I think that if you type the required confirmation you should be able to proceed.

Comment: Please change i do no

Comment: Did you run apt-get update before running apt-get -f install? And are you using i386 architecture? If not you could just remove the i386 packages with sudo apt-get remove *:i386

Comment: How are you trying to install ? Through Ubuntu software center or Terminal ? I guess, Terminal. Try installing using Ubuntu Software Center. See if there is still a problem.

Comment: How I install lamp in software center

Comment: Looks like we have the same error https://askubuntu.com/questions/941935/libtinfo-libtag1-vanilla-libical1a-libtag1c2a I am trying `dselect`