# libtinfo, libtag1-vanilla, libical1a, libtag1c2a

Tags: 16.04, dpkg, do-release-upgrade, gstreamer

On upgrading to 16.04 LTS, I have come to the following unresolvable dependencies

```
root@computer:/opt# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-good : Depends: libtag1v5 (>= 1.9.1-2.4ubuntu1) but it is not installed
 libncurses5 : Depends: libtinfo5 (= 6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1) but 6.0+20161126-1 is installed
 libncurses5-dev : Depends: libtinfo5 (= 6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1) but 6.0+20161126-1 is installed
 libtinfo-dev : Depends: libtinfo5 (= 6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1) but 6.0+20161126-1 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

If I then download `libtag1v5 1.9.1.2.4ubuntu1` manually,

```
root@computer:/opt# dpkg -i libtag1v5_1.9.1-2.4ubuntu1_i386.deb
Selecting previously unselected package libtag1v5:i386.
dpkg: considering removing libtag1c2a in favour of libtag1v5:i386 ...
dpkg: libtag1c2a is not properly installed; ignoring any dependencies on it
dpkg: yes, will remove libtag1c2a in favour of libtag1v5:i386
(Reading database ... 1081893 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libtag1v5_1.9.1-2.4ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libtag1v5:i386 (1.9.1-2.4ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libtag1v5:i386:
 libtag1v5:i386 depends on libtag1v5-vanilla (= 1.9.1-2.4ubuntu1); however:
  Package libtag1v5-vanilla:i386 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libtag1v5:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libtag1v5:i386
```

and chasing *that* dependency problem…

```
root@computer:/opt# dpkg -r libtag1c2a
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove libtag1c2a, only the config
 files of which are on the system; use --purge to remove them too

root@computer:/opt# dpkg  --purge libtag1c2a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libtag1c2a:
 gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386 depends on libtag1c2a (>= 1.5).

dpkg: error processing package libtag1c2a (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libtag1c2a
```

where `gstreamer1.0-plugins-good` is the very package I am trying to correct in the first place.

---

#### I can’t tell if my brain is fried or if I have really encountered a circular reference.

⋮

I also *think* I have come to circular dependencies with `libtinfo`, `libtag*`, `libtag*vanilla`, and `libncursesw5`. For example with `libtinfo`:

```
root@computer:/opt# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gstreamer0.10-plugins-good : Depends: libtag1c2a (>= 1.5) but it is not installable
 libncurses5 : Depends: libtinfo5 (= 6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1) but 6.0+20161126-1 is installed
 libncurses5-dev : Depends: libtinfo5 (= 6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1) but 6.0+20161126-1 is installed
 libtag1v5 : Depends: libtag1v5-vanilla (= 1.9.1-2.4ubuntu1) but it is not installed
 libtinfo-dev : Depends: libtinfo5 (= 6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1) but 6.0+20161126-1 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

OK, so let's `dpkg -i` `libtinfo5 (= 6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1)`…

```
root@computer:/opt# dpkg -i libtinfo5_6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1_i386.deb 
dpkg: warning: downgrading libtinfo5:i386 from 6.0+20161126-1 to 6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1
(Reading database ... 1081890 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libtinfo5_6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libtinfo5:i386 (6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1) over (6.0+20161126-1) ...
Setting up libtinfo5:i386 (6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...




root@computer:/opt# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gstreamer0.10-plugins-good : Depends: libtag1c2a (>= 1.5) but it is not installable
 libncursesw5 : Depends: libtinfo5 (= 6.0+20161126-1) but 6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1 is installed
 libtag1v5 : Depends: libtag1v5-vanilla (= 1.9.1-2.4ubuntu1) but it is not installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

So `libncursesw5` requires `libtinfo5 (= 6.0+20161126-1)`, whereas another library requires the `20160213` version. Additionally, `libncursesw5` is not removable because `procps` depends on it, and vital system components  which *cannot* be removed (eg, `xdm`) depend on `procps`.

```
root@computer:/opt# dpkg -i libtinfo5_6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1_i386.deb 
dpkg: warning: downgrading libtinfo5:i386 from 6.0+20161126-1 to 6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1
(Reading database ... 1081890 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libtinfo5_6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libtinfo5:i386 (6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1) over (6.0+20161126-1) ...
Setting up libtinfo5:i386 (6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
root@computer:/opt# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gstreamer0.10-plugins-good : Depends: libtag1c2a (>= 1.5) but it is not installable
 libncursesw5 : Depends: libtinfo5 (= 6.0+20161126-1) but 6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1 is installed
 libtag1v5 : Depends: libtag1v5-vanilla (= 1.9.1-2.4ubuntu1) but it is not installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
root@computer:/opt# ls libtag*
libtag1c2a_1.5-3_i386.deb    libtag1v5_1.11.1+dfsg.1-0.1_i386.deb  libtag1v5-vanilla_1.11.1+dfsg.1-0.1_i386.deb  libtag1-vanilla_1.9.1-2_i386.deb
libtag1c2a_1.9.1-2_i386.deb  libtag1v5_1.9.1-2.4ubuntu1_i386.deb   libtag1v5-vanilla_1.9.1-2.4ubuntu1_i386.deb
root@computer:/opt# dpkg -i libtag1c2a_1.5-3_i386.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package libtag1c2a.
dpkg: regarding libtag1c2a_1.5-3_i386.deb containing libtag1c2a:
 libtag1v5:i386 conflicts with libtag1c2a
  libtag1c2a (version 1.5-3) is to be installed.

dpkg: error processing archive libtag1c2a_1.5-3_i386.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing libtag1c2a
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libtag1c2a_1.5-3_i386.deb
root@computer:/opt# dpkg -r libtag1v5
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libtag1v5:i386:
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 depends on libtag1v5 (>= 1.9.1-2.4ubuntu1).

dpkg: error processing package libtag1v5:i386 (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libtag1v5:i386
```

Comment: It appears you've installed packages from Debian. If so too bad for you. I'd suggest locating all such packages, then find the proper Ubuntu 16.04 packages & installing en masse with dpkg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124845/eerror-pkgproblemresolverresolve-generated-breaks-this-may-be-caused-by-hel)

Answer (score 0):

the very old ([hardy](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ncurses/5.6+20071124-1ubuntu2/+build/523298)) `libncursesw5_5.6+20071124-1ubuntu1_i386.deb` seems like what was necessary.

`dselect` is easier than `dpkg`.

---

Note from @doug’s comment that installing packages from debian sid repos is a bad idea. The `.deb` files need to have `*ubuntu*` in the name.